# How to change contents of a text type column of a table in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have created a table in laravel and I'm using mysql for database. And one of it's columns is text type.Now I want to change contents of the column but I don't want to update it I just want to edit some of the data where I inserted to that column. How can I do this?

Comment: your question is not clear, you want to change the column type or the columns content?

Comment: I want to edit contents

Answer (score 0):

You can use then a `Mutator` inside the Model you want:

```
class YourModel extends Model
{

    public function getYourAttribute($value)
    {
        return //something
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more please I'm new in laravel.

Comment: Mutators allow you to modify the value that comes from the database the moment its retrieved from the database, in other words, let's say per example in your USER table you have a field called "score" and you want everytime you retrieve this field to multiply it by 2, so in order to do that, you  write a function in the user model called `getScoreAttribute($value){return $this->score*2;}` and that way when you do `$user->score` you'll have always the value multiplied by 2, understand?